# android:layout_toLeftOf in RelativeLayout not working when I setX on left view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains two `ImageView`s and a `View` between them, both `ImageView`s are aligned to the `View` sibling [i.e. right `ImageView` is aligned to right side of the view, same with the left].

like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="106dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/euqualizer"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/euqualizer"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/euqualizer"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the java code I want to move the view's location according to the direction of the touch motion i.e. using setX() on the view.

like this:

```
  img1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
  img2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
  View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            startDrag_X = event.getX();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                            float x_delta = event.getX() - startDrag_X;
                            euqualizer.setX(euqualizer.getX() + x_delta);

                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                            startDrag_X = -1;
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        };
```

But for some reason although, the view does successfully relocate itself as I expected it to do, but the ImageViews which are aligned to the views sides do not move at all

what am I doing wrong?